# jquery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

when i mouse out from a ul li, i want to hide the dropdown ul what i w'll do

Answer (score 1):

**This is what I think you meant:**

you can use a combination of the [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event and the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) event

```
$("ul").hover(
    function(){ $("li", this).toggle(); }
);
```

---

But if you literally meant hiding the ul after mouseout of the li then try this:

```
$("ul li").mouseout(
    function(){ $(this).closest("ul").hide(); }
);
```

Comment: I would think s/he meant hiding the "li" as well b/c hiding the ul will also hide the menu.

Comment: @nolabel right... which seems a little odd, but who knows what it's for